# How to watch a collection for insert and delete using aggregation in mongodb and nodejs?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to [watch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/) the [change stream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/) of a collection, but filter it by `operationType` (`insert`, `delete`) and some fields.

```
let collection = client.db('testdb').collection('test');
```

this returns all [event types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/)

```
collection.watch().on('change', result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

this will return only insert

```
collection.watch(
    [{
        $match: { 'fullDocument.name': 'Tom' }
    }]
).on('change', result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

this returns only insert

```
collection.watch(
    [{
        $match: {
            $and: [ { 'fullDocument.name': 'Tom' }, { $or: [ { 'operationType': 'insert' }, { 'operationType': 'delete' } ] } ]
        }
    }]
).on('change', result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`fullDocument` is omitted in delete events, so `'fullDocument.name': 'Tom'` will never be true.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/#delete-event